# Error when copy from CollectionView cell (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, drag-and-drop, copy, uicollectionviewcell

I make **Drag and Drop** app.

He is work fine, but copy from cell not work.

When i tap on collection view cell, i have error.

**My code for copy:**

```
let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! TextCollectionViewCell
UIPasteboard.general.string = cell.textLabel?.text
```

**cellForItemAt**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let item = everitems[indexPath.row]

    switch item {
    case .text(let content):
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "TextCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TextCollectionViewCell
        cell.configureWithText(content)
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
        cell.layer.masksToBounds = true
        return cell
    case .image(let content):
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ImageCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ImageCollectionViewCell
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
        cell.layer.masksToBounds = true
        cell.configureWithImage(content)
        return cell
    }
}
```

**Error - Thread 1: signal SIGABRT**

> 2018-04-02 19:54:35.520913+0500 DragBook[6891:189120] [MC] Reading
>   from private effective user settings. Could not cast value of type
>   'DragBook.ImageCollectionViewCell' (0x10e67e0e0) to
>   'DragBook.TextCollectionViewCell' (0x10e67e4e0). 2018-04-02
>   19:54:48.631190+0500 DragBook[6891:189120] Could not cast value of
>   type 'DragBook.ImageCollectionViewCell' (0x10e67e0e0) to
>   'DragBook.TextCollectionViewCell' (0x10e67e4e0). (lldb)

**Solution:**

```
if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? ImageCollectionViewCell{
      UIPasteboard.general.image = cell.imageView?.image
      print("Image")
} else if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? TextCollectionViewCell{
      UIPasteboard.general.string = cell.textLabel?.text
      print("Text")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the cell may be imageCell and you force cast it as textCell

```
if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? TextCollectionViewCell{

}
else
{
    /// it's image cell
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! ImageCollectionViewCell

}
```

Comment: Happy coding :)